# Finding if values in two columns exist

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns of dates and I want to run a query that returns TRUE if there is a date in existence in the first column and in existence in the second column.

I know how to do it when I'm looking for a match (if the data entry in column A is the SAME as the entry in column B), but I don't know know how to find if data entry in column A and B are in existence.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The question could be read in multiple ways, the explanation is not clear. Existing data in the same row or anywhere in the table? What to return exactly? No Postgres version, no table definition, no sample data, no code example. This is not a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If data in a column is present, it `IS NOT NULL`. You can query for that on both columns, with and `AND` clause to get your result:

```
SELECT (date1 IS NOT NULL AND date2 IS NOT NULL) AS both_dates
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, rephrasing:

*For any two entries in table `x` with `date` columns `a` and `b`, is there some pair of rows `x1` and `x2` where `x1.a = x2.b`?*

If that's what you're trying to do, you want a *self-join*, e.g, presuming the presence of a single key column named `id`:

```
SELECT x1.id, x2.id, x1.a AS x1_a_x2_b
FROM mytable x1
  INNER JOIN mytable x2 ON (x1.a = x2.b);
```